# Create a project with Storyboard, Cocos2D and ARC enabled

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, xcode4.5

I'm using XCode 4.5.2 to create an iOS universal application.

I'd like to use its storyboard for my application. Normally, I create new project by choosing New > Project > Single view project > check Use storyboard.

Sometimes in my application, I need to use Cocos2D for complex animation (no need to interactive with it, only for presentation).

My animation was created using CocosBuilder which works with Cocos2D 2.0 and CCBReader library.

I tried to add Cocos2D to my existing project by:

1. Adding Cocos2D folder (include Support, Platforms, kazmath folders).
2. Try thing like edit -fno-obj-arc to those *.m files in Build Phases/Compile Sources.

But when I build project, the ARC errors are still there.

**#Question:**

1. How could I implement Cocos2D into existing XCode 4.3/4.5 project?
2. If I create a Cocos2D template project, could I activate ARC for rest of my project, those non-Cocos2D classes?

I successfully created an project with Cocos2D inside a UIView from a Cocos2D template as [Ray's post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4817/how-to-integrate-cocos2d-and-uikit) but now I want things (may be) a little more complicated.

Comment: Enable ARC: http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enable-arc-cocos2d-project-video-tutorial/

Comment: @LearnCocos2D hi Steffen, love to hear from you :) The video is helped when I create a Cocos2D template project but, what I want is create a Single View template then add Cocos2D libs back to it. Only Cocos2D needed, not Denshion or Chipmunk :) Please provide me you opinion about this case.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Would you mind a blog post how to implement Cocos2D into a storyboard project with XCode 4.3+? As Cocos2D would be use sometimes in some ViewControllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With many help from @Setrio, @LearnCocos2D and lot of Googling, I finally fixed it.

My project is combined from Cocos2D, Storyboard, ARC enabled and CocosBuilder.

First, create a project with SingleView selection (ARC enabled of course).

Then download the Cocos2D ARC enabled here https://github.com/LearnCocos2D/cocos2d-iphone-arc-templates thanks to Steffen!

Add its libs into your project as pointed out here http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enable-arc-cocos2d-project-video-tutorial/ (brilliant, works like charm)

Create storyboard with Cocos2D as this tutorial (sample included) http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/

All things work together now. Beautiful. I love Cocos2D :)

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't know off the top of my head.
2. Yes, I have done this very thing with my latest Cocos2D-iOS project.  I converted my project to ARC with the automatic refactoring tool, and I simply excluded all the Cocos2D library files from the process.  for the most part the refactoring went smoothly and my project was up and running again in no time.

Comment: love to know how you could do it! Is it something like Edit > Refactor? Cuz I tried it once and failed.

Comment: Here's a good tutorial: [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

I found this link/tutorial useful for a project similar to this one.

http://www.tinytimgames.com/2012/02/07/cocos2d-and-storyboards/

Basically you add support for cocos2d inside the view controllers. You have to use cocos2d as a library and that solves most of the issues.

Comment: Hmm, I think the difficult part is, how to add Cocos2D libs (Cocos2D, Kazmath atc.) into current project and make them work together. There're so many ways and I found them not working in my case.

Comment: Just add the cocos2d-iphone to your project, that make all available. Try that and update the post with your issues, i have a working project UIKit based so if you need help i do my best.

Comment: thanks much, I make it work :) please refer to my answer below.